# OpenOffice pyuno "select all"

Tags: python, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc, uno, pyuno

Does anyone know how to use the OO uno bridge api to "select all" in a Calc sheet?

Alternatively, finding the maximum used row and column number would work.

What I want to do is apply a format to all the cells in the spreadsheet.

(The reason being that I'm saving the sheet as csv, so numbers are not accurately saved unless the format provides enough decimal places.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have already connected to OpenOffice and `document` is a spreadsheet that has been opened or created.

```
#get the sheet you want to work with, I'm just going to grab the first sheet
sheets = document.getSheets().createEnumeration()
sheet = sheets.nextElement()

#start with a range on the first cell
range = sheet.getCellRangeByPosition( 0, 0, 0, 0 )

#expand to full extend of the used area
range.gotoEndOfUsedArea( True ) #true for expand selection

#no do whatever formatting things you want to do
```

Comment: Two things: Firstly, I don't think it is a good idea to use 'range' as a variable in python because it conflicts with Python range function. Secondly, as of July 2018 I did not get the method 'gotoEndOfUsedArea' with the range object. Solution by @Daniel worked though.

Comment: This did work 7 years ago. ;)  Glad you got the solution you needed.

Answer (score 2):

I do get an error (Attribute Error) with the line:

> range.gotoEndOfUsedArea(True)

By combining the two information at
1: http://nab.pcug.org.au/transferdemo_oocalc.py
and 2: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Cells_and_Ranges

I came up with the following solution:

```
def getLastActiveCell(sheet):
    """returns the last used column and row of the provided sheet 
    (ie the last cell in the range containing something other than '')"""
    #create a cursor for the whole sheet using OO interface XSheetCellRange 
    cursor = sheet.createCursor()
    #goto the last used cell
    cursor.gotoEndOfUsedArea(True)
    #grab that positions "coordinates"
    address = cursor.RangeAddress
    endcol = address.EndColumn
    endrow = address.EndRow
    #and pass them back
    return endcol,endrow
```

you may then access those values in your code like this:

```
lastCell = getLastActiveCell(sheetObject)
print lastCell[0] #Column
print lastCell[1] #Row
```

and create a range

```
 range = sheetObject.getCellRangeByPosition( 0, 0, lastCell[0], lastCell[1] )
```

or whatever for further work.

Comment: Thanks for this - helped me as documentation is not easy to come across. However, two things to note in code above:  (1) cursor = tabelle.createCursor()' should be 'cursor = sheet.createCursor()', (2) Things seem to have changed since the snippet was written. I had to use 'address.value.EndRow' and 'address.value.EndColumn' to access end row and end column respectively.

Comment: For me being German tabelle=sheet slipped in by mistake. I did edit my post. I will have to check (2) another time. But yes could well be since some time passed by. :-)